Replace multiple lines in a file with another command
I can find all files in a directory with a particular name with find:
find . -name hello.mk

Inside each hello.mk I need to replace lines 9 and 10 with a single line, as shown below:
9:    HELLO_LATEST = $(shell \
10:     curl -f -s https://api.github.com/repos/org/repo/releases | jq -r 'map(select(.prerelease)) | .[0].tag_name')

with
9: HELLO_LATEST = $(shell curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/org/repo/releases  | grep tag_name | cut -d\" -f4)

and I want to do it in place. How can I accomplish that in bash?

This might help you: How can I use sed to replace a multi-line string?

@Devon Note that this question is very explicit in that it needs to replace lines 9 and 10 rather than any two lines matching some pattern.  This is a stricter criteria than in the other question.

With sed, just change line 9 and 10 to the have the text you want:
sed '9,10c \
HELLO_LATEST = $(shell curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/org/repo/releases  | grep tag_name | cut -d\" -f4)' hello.mk

The c command changes the addressed lines to the content after the \ and newline.  If you want to insert multiple lines, each internal newline has to be escaped by \:
sed '9,10c \
HELLO_LATEST = $(shell curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/org/repo/releases  | grep tag_name | cut -d\" -f4)\
moar\
data\
here' hello.mk

Use sed -i if you want to write this back to the original file using GNU sed.
Calling this from find:
find . -name hello.mk -exec sed ... {} \;


Note too that the code
grep tag_name | cut -d\" -f4

that you are replacing
jq -r 'map(select(.prerelease)) | .[0].tag_name'

with, could be better written like
jq -r '.[].tag_name'

This would give you the values of all tag_name keys from the top-level array (whereas the old expression would give you the first tag_name value of the entries that had true prerelease values).
If you want the first tag_name value, use
jq -r 'first.tag_name'

Don't try to use grep on the JSON data as the string vlue would additionally have to be decoded from having been JSON-encoded.

Using any awk:
find . -name hello.mk -exec awk '
    NR ==  9 { $0 = "HELLO_LATEST = $(shell curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/org/repo/releases  | grep tag_name | cut -d\\\" -f4)" }
    NR != 10 { vals[++numLines] = $0 }
    END {
        for ( i=1; i<=numLines; i++ ) {
            print vals[i] > FILENAME
        }
    }
' {} \;

GNU awk has -i inplace while sed, perl, ruby, python, etc. all have -i for what they call "in place" editing but they all create/use a temp file behind the scenes while the above works without creating any temp file using only functionality that exists on all Unix boxes as it's using the mandatory POSIX tool, awk. The built in awk variable FILENAME contains the name of the file currently being read/processed by the awk script, so the script above will modify whatever file it is given.
Note that I'm ending the find command with {} \;, not {} + to ensure awk gets called 1 file at a time, the solution gets a bit trickier if awk were to be called with multiple files at once.
